# How to find max(sortnumber) on item code in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have following SQL Server table `ITEM`:

```
+------------+-----------+------+--------+-----------+------------+
|    Date    | item_code | name | in/out | total_qty | SortNumber |
+------------+-----------+------+--------+-----------+------------+
| 08/07/2019 |       001 | A    |    -50 |       100 |          8 |
| 07/07/2019 |       001 | A    |     50 |       100 |          7 |
| 06/07/2019 |       003 | C    |     25 |        25 |          6 |
| 05/07/2019 |       001 | A    |     50 |        50 |          5 |
| 04/07/2019 |       002 | B    |    100 |       200 |          4 |
| 03/07/2019 |       003 | C    |    -25 |         0 |          3 |
| 02/07/2019 |       003 | C    |     25 |        25 |          2 |
| 01/07/2019 |       002 | B    |    100 |       100 |          1 |
+------------+-----------+------+--------+-----------+------------+
```

I've tried:

```
select itemcode, max(Sort_Number) 
from ITEM
group by item_code 
order by item_code asc
```

but I want result:

```
+---------------------+-----------+------------------+
| Distinct(item_code) | Total_qty | Max(Sort_Number) |
+---------------------+-----------+------------------+
| 001                 | 100       | 8                |
| 002                 | 200       | 4                |
| 003                 | 25        | 6                |
+---------------------+-----------+------------------+
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below query gives you the desired result  -

```
With cteItem  as
(
 select item_code, total_qty, SortNumber, 
 Row_Number() over (partition by item_code order by SortNumber desc)  maxSortNumber
 from ITEM 
)
select item_code, total_qty, SortNumber from cteItem where maxSortNumber = 1
```

Comment: Thank you Mukesh Arora, I try on my tables, and its work, but  I want checked again.. Thank you again..

Answer (score 0):

just need to add `max(sort_number)` to your query

```
select item_code ,max(total_qty), max(sort_number)
from ITEM
group by item_code 
order by item_code asc
```

Comment: I'm sorry, i just edited, I get wrong, on max(total_qty) become max(sort_number)